# Changed value on AngularJS Service not triggering watch within directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having an issue getting a watch to work within a directive. I've put together a simple example here. http://plnkr.co/edit/A7zbrsh8gJhdpM30ZH2P

I have a service and two directives. One directive changes a property in the service, and another directive has a watch on that property. I expected the watch to fire when the property is changed but it doesn't.

I've seen a few other questions like this on the site, but the accepted solutions on them have not worked here. I've considered using $broadcast or trying to implement an observer, but it seems like this should work and I don't want to over complicate things if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.currentObject = newObject;
```

use

```
angular.copy(newObject, this.currentObject);
```

With the original code, the `viewer` directive is watching the original object, `{}`.  When `currentObject` is set to `newObject`, the $watch is still looking for a change to the original object, not `newObject`.

angular.copy() modifies the original object, so the $watch sees that change.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was probably something simple. 

Another thread had mentioned that passing the third property of the watch as true would handle that, so I had stopped investigating that route.

Answer (score 28):

Mark Rajcok' answer is incomplete. Even with angular.copy(), $watch listener will be called once and never again.

You need to $watch a function:

```
$scope.$watch(

  // This is the important part
  function() {
    return demoService.currentObject;
  },

  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('demoService.currentObject has been changed');
    // Do whatever you want with demoService.currenctObject
  },
  true
);
```

Here the plunker that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/0mav32?p=preview

Open your browser console to see that both the directive and the demoService2 are notified about demoService.currentObject changes.

And btw angular.copy() is not even needed in this example.

Comment: Perfect answer. This is the proper way to do it.